# Problem in understanding proof of Alternating Series Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am having problems understanding the second part of the theorem. However, I will state the full theorem, as well as the full proof, since proof of the first part is used for the second part. I have put in **bold** the part of the theorem whose proof I didn't understand.

> ## Alternating Series Theorem:
>
> If $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge ... \ge a_n \ge ... \ge 0$ and $\lim a_n = 0$, then the alternating series $\sum(-1)^{n+1}a_n$ converges. **Moreover, the partial sums $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}a_k$ satisfy $|s-s_n| \le a_n$ for all $n$.**

> ### Proof:
>
> Note that the subsequence $s_{2n}$ is increasing, and $s_{2n-1}$ is decreasing. Also note that $s_{2n} \le s_{2n+1}$ for all $n$. Now, we claim
> $$s_{2m} \le s_{2m+1} \text{ for all } m,n \in \mathbb N \text{....(1)}$$
> Case 1: $m \ge n$ 
> In this case, (1) holds because $s_{2n+1} \ge s_{2m+1} \ge s_{2m}$ 
> Case 2: $m \le n$ 
> in this case, (1) holds because $s_{2m} \le s_{2n} \le s_{2n+1}$
>
> Due to (1), we see that $(s_{2n})$ is an increasing subsequence of $(s_n)$ bounded above by each odd partial sum, and $(s_{2n+1})$ is a decreasing subsequence of $({s_n})$ bounded below by each even partial sum. Thus, these subsequences converge, say to $s$ and $t$.
> $$t-s = \lim_{n \to \infty}s_{2n+1} - \lim_{n \to \infty}s_{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(s_{2n+1}-s_{2n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1} = 0$$
> So $s=t$. It follows that $\lim s_n = s$
>
> **To check the last claim, note that $s_{2k} \le s \le s_{2k+1}$, so both $s_{2k+1}-s$ and $s-s_{2k}$ are clearly bounded by $s_{2k+1}-s_{2k} = a_{2k+1} \le a_{2k}$. So, whether $n$ is even or odd, we have $|s-s_n| \le a_n$**

I do not understand how the inequality $s_{2k} \le s \le s_{2k+1}$ is true(I'm not arguing it is false, I just don't understand how it is true). I also don't understand the part where $s_{2k+1}-s$ and $s-s_{2k}$ are bounded by $s_{2k+1}-s_{2k} = a_{2k+1} \le a_{2k}$. Can someone please explain. Thanks.

Comment: $s_{2k} \le s$ because $(s_{2k})$ is increasing and converges to $s.$ And $s_{2k+1} \ge s$ because $(s_{2k+1})$ is decreasing and converges to $s.$ And $s_{2k+1}-s\le s_{2k+1}-s_{2k}$ because $s_{2k}\le s.$ And $s-s_{2k}\le s_{2k+1}-s_{2k}$ because $s\le s_{2k+1}.$ By definition of $s_n,$ $s_{2k+1}-s_{2k}=(-1)^{(2k+1)+1}a_{2k+1}=a_{2k+1}.$ And by hypothesis, $a_{n+1}\le a_n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(s_{2k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is an increasing sequence and $s$ is its limit, then each $s_{2k}$ is smaller than or equal to $s$. A similar argument shows that each $s_{2k+1}$ is greater than or equal to $s$.

On the other hand, for each natural $k$ you have$$s_{2k+1}-s\leqslant s_{2k+1}-s_{2k}=a_{2k+1}$$and$$s-s_{2k}\leqslant s_{2k+1}-s_{2k}=a_{2k+1}\leqslant a_{2k}.$$And this show that, for each natural $n$, $|s-s_n|\leqslant a_n$.